# Whats does the random range mean?

Tags: arrays, optimization, random, outofrangeexception

I'm using unity's random.value function (I think i saw this behavior also somewhere else), which as the documentation states works as follows.

> Both 0.0 and 1.0 may be returned by this property. This behaviour is different to that of many other random number generators which return a value less than but never exactly equal to 1.0.

Now when using this method somewhat like this

```
int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int number = array[(int)(Random.value * array.length)];
```

do i have to worry about getting an ArrayOutOfRangeException, when all planets are lined up? And does that mean that i'm forced to do it like this for the sake of me beeing abled to sleep at night?

```
int number = array[(int)((Random.value - Float.epsilon) * array.length)];
```

Further i would like to know why someone would create a random function that isnt returning numbers only smaller than one? Is there any hidden benefit in doing it that way?

Comment: Oh yuck. Bad unity.

Comment: But Unity supports `Random.Range(int, int)` which is much clearer anyway...

Comment: @JonSkeet The [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random-value.html) says exactly the opposite. A value 0.0 [inclusive] and 1.0 [**inclusive**].

Comment: @T.Grumser: Whoops! Had misread. Thanks for the correction. Doh!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you shouldn't use that. If it does return 1.0, you'll have problems. Frankly I think it was an API design mistake on Unity's part.

However, this is not how I would recommend that you write the code anyway. Instead, use the [`Random.Range` method](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html):

```
int number = array[Random.Range(0, array.Length)];
```

There, the overload accepting `int` values treats the maximum as *exclusive* rather than inclusive.

---

Comment: Thanks, i did not know about the Random.Range method - Strange that unity made a mistake like that.

Comment: @T.Grumser: I suspect it was an early mistake, and can't be fixed in case someone has a fixed-seed that they know *should* produce 1.0 :(